# Problem using \noopsort to sort on 'year' using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

In my efforts to familiarise myself with `BIBTeX` and `natbib`, I've been playing with the `xampl.bib` database which is shipped with the TeXLive 2011 distribution.  I created a document (using the `plainnat.bst`style) which cited every entry in the database.  Compiling the document produced console output as follows (after running PDFLaTeX for the third time):

```
(./xampl-citations.tex
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   \def
l.15 {\citeref{book-full}
                         }
?
```

`\citeref` is a command I define so that I can change the citation style easily.  It appears as follows in the document preamble:

```
\newcommand{\refcolor}{\color{Black}}
\newcommand{\citeref}{\refcolor \citep}
```

After a process of elimination (ie by changing entries in the `xampl.bib` database using `JabRef`), I've pinned the problem down to entries in the 'year' field of the following form:

```
{\noopsort{1973c}}1981
```

As far as I can tell `\noopsort` is correctly defined in the preamble of the `xampl.bib` file:

```
@PREAMBLE{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} "
# "\newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1} "
# "\newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} "
# "\newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1} " }
```

As you might imagine, I've done a fair amount of searching around to see if anyone else has reported a similar problem, and I've found a question on this resource which suggests that the problem might be an excess of curly brackets in the `.bib` file:

[natbib-error-when-citing-paper-with-similar-authors-and-same-year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/natbib-error-when-citing-paper-with-similar-authors-and-same-year)

Indeed, an example section from my `xampl.bib` file does suggest that the entries contain a superfluous pair of curly brackets:

```
@BOOK{book-full,
  title = {Seminumerical Algorithms},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {{\noopsort{1973c}}1981},
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  volume = {2},
  series = {The Art of Computer Programming},
  address = {Reading, Massachusetts},
  edition = {Second},
  month = {10~} # jan,
  note = {This is a full BOOK entry},
  fileno = {91}
}
```

The problem is – what do I do about it?  The way my set-up works is that I hold my master database in EndNote and then export entries (required fields only) into `JabRef` where I perform the necessary tweaks for `LaTeX`.  This system works well for me, so I don't particularly want to change it.  However, if surplus curly brackets is the cause of the problem, then how do I prevent them appearing in the `.bib` file?

This is not a hypothetical question, because I will need occasionally to adjust the sort order of entries in my thesis bibliography – so I need to find a way to do it.  If the `\noopsort` method cannot be made to work, are there any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the supplementary pair of braces, which is however necessary for correct sorting. You should try `biblatex`, really, because it provides different fields for sorting dates.

A possible patch is to write, after loading `natbib`,

```
\makeatletter
\let\NAT@bare@aux\NAT@bare
\def\NAT@bare#1(#2){%
 \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
   \unexpanded{\NAT@bare@aux#1}(\@firstofone#2)}\x}
\makeatother
```

This will swallow the offending part, while keeping the correct sorting order.

The problem is in what's presented to LaTeX and `natbib` to interpret. If you look at the `.bbl` file, you'll see that the entry starts with

```
\bibitem[Knuth({\noopsort{1973c}}1981)]{book-full}
```

Now `natbib` uses this to produce the results from `\citep{book-full}` (or `\citet`), by applying various commands. The relevant one (that I found with some `grep` search) is `\NAT@bare` that requires its arguments in the form

```
\def\NAT@bare#1(#2)#3(@)#4\@nil#5{%
```

The relevant part is `#1(#2)`, which is derived from the argument to `\bibitem` in brackets; `natbib` wants to perform a numeric check, assuming that what's in parentheses is the year. But it finds `{\noopsort{1973c}}1981` and this breaks off. So I make an alias to the original `\NAT@bare` command, calling it `\NAT@bare@aux` and do

```
\def\NAT@bare#1(#2){%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \unexpanded{\NAT@bare@aux#1}(\@firstofone#2)}\x}
```

So, when `natbib` wants to execute `\NAT@bare` (it's so instructed by other macros), it will take the argument `Knuth({\noopsort{1973c}1981}) and perform an`\edef`; thus`\x` will be defined as the result of completely expanding

```
\endgroup\unexpanded{\NAT@bare@aux Knuth}(\@firstofone{\noopsort{1973c}}1981)
```

The job of `\@firstofone` is just to strip the braces, and the expansion of `\noopsort{1973c}` is just empty. So at the end LaTeX will see

```
\NAT@bare@aux Knuth(1981)
```

which is in the right format. The `\endgroup` balances the `\begingroup` and vanishes together with the definition of `\x` which has already done its job.

If the entry is normal, say `\bibitem[Author(2012)]` (by the way, Happy New Year), `\x` will be defined as the full expansion of

```
\endgroup\unexpanded{\NAT@bare@aux Author}(\@firstofone 2012)
```

and `\@firstofone 2` will simply return `2`, so in the end LaTeX will see

```
\NAT@bare@aux Author(2012)
```

as it should.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg, that does the trick!  I wish I understood the code above, but I guess I need to learn to walk before I can run.  It has occurred to me to have a look at `biblatex`, but I thought I'd get familiar with `bibtex` first.  My thesis isn't due for another 2 years and 9 months, so I've got plenty of time to get to grips with the intracies of `latex`!

Comment: @MarkBirtwistle I've added some explanations

Comment: @Mark: I highly recommend `biblatex`! Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex.

Comment: @egreg, many thanks for your comprehensive explanations – I will need to spend a little time going through them and trying to understand them.  @lockstep, you're very persuasive.  As I have a full 2 years and 9 months before my thesis submission date, I have plenty of time to get my head around `biblatex'!

Comment: @MarkBirtwistle Study `biblatex`, then. It's vastly more powerful than `natbib`.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that your `\refcite` command invokes natbib's `\citep` command, but it does so without explicitly noting that `\citep` takes an argument. A possible solution -- I say *possible* because I haven't actually tried it out -- would be to have the following commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}  % or: \usepackage{color}
...
\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
\newcommand{\refcolor}{Black}
\newcommand{\citeref}[1]{\textcolor{\refcolor}{\citep{#1}}}
```

Comment: funnily enough I was thinking along the same lines – it would be useful to be able to insert page and/or chapter numbers into a citation.  After a lot of playing around, I've managed to get it to work with a slight modification of the code you propose:

Comment: Good God @Mico, five minutes doesn't give you much time for editing!  The modified code is `\newcommand{\citeref}[1]{\refcolor \citep[#1]}`.  In the text I cite references either as `\citeref{}{_citationkey_}` or `\citeref{p _xx_}{_citationkey_}`.  Many thanks for your input, much appreciated.